# php count of array of arrays - different value than expected

Tags: php, arrays, count

I am having a brain fart on this one because I can't figure out how to get this count to return as expected :

```
$ajax_result['data'] = array('ID' => 0, 'Timestamp' => $_POST['end_date'] * 1000, 'Total' => 0);

echo count($ajax_result['data']);
```

The above returns 3 - I am expecting it to return 1 or would like it to (1 array in the array).  `$ajax_result['data']` can possibly contain many arrays and that is the total I need to get.

The format of this needs to stay the same because these results are used by a plugin that needs them in this format.

Comment: You’re counting the number of elements in the array: ID, Timestamp, and Total. Perhaps you’re looking for `is_array($ajax_result['data'])`?

Comment: on re-reading your question, you are mistaken on a point: 'data' will not contain many arrays. It might very well contain an *array of arrays* though. So the question is how can you distinguish between the two? And frankly, this doesn’t even make sense... why not use [0] for a single instance? You’ve got some serious technical debt here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your desired result (and probably to have your code work correctly anyway), you need to make `$ajax_result['data']` a multi-dimensional array:

```
$ajax_result['data'] = array(array('ID' => 0, 'Timestamp' => $_POST['end_date'] * 1000, 'Total' => 0));
```

`count($ajax_result['data'])` will now return 1.

Then you can push new values into the array e.g.:

```
$ajax_result['data'][] = array('ID' => 1, 'Timestamp' => $_POST['end_date'] * 1000, 'Total' => 2);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ucaqW)

Comment: `$ajax_result['data'][] = ` ... this is part of a switch statement and in every single other one I have the ending [] on this variable... except for this one.  That is all I was missing and kept looking over it.  Thanks for pointing this out!  I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: You're definitely right about that.  It wouldn't be the first time and I'm sure won't be the last :)  These are the ones that drive you nuts then you can only laugh about it after.

Comment: @user756659 yup, been there, done that! :)